# How to implement telegram style pop up in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, popup

When the popup shows up, other areas should be touchable. How one can achieve this behavior?:

[image]

Comment: Please note that there are multiple answers, you need the one where the overlay does not block using the underlying controls. So please read it all, not just the accepted answer.